# "Ich möchte.." als Antwort auf "Willst du.."?

Tags: politeness, informal

Jemand hat mich gerade gefragt: "Willst du 'nen Kaffee?". Ich habe ihm geantwortet: "Ja ich will". Eine Dritte hat mich korrigiert: "Du solltest nicht mit ***ich will*** antworten, sondern mit ***ich möchte***".

Stimmt das in diesem Fall? Ich meine, hätte ich mir selbst einen Kaffee bestellt, dann würde ich sicherlich sagen: "Ich *möchte* einen Kaffee haben". Aber als Antwort auf "Willst du?", hätte ich das nie gedacht.

Comment: "Willst Du diesen Kaffee zur Braut nehmen, lieben und ehren ..." ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Also, du kannst antworten mit

> Ja ich will (1)

oder mit

> Ja möchte ich (2)

oder natuerlich mit nur "Ja bitte". (2) ist höflicher als (1), deswegen sollte man (2) nehmen. Ich sage jedoch immer "Ja" oder "Ja bitte". "Willst du", kannst du fast immer mit "Ja bitte" oder "Nein danke" beantworten.

Comment: Meine Lieblingsantwort ist fast immer *"Ja, gerne"*.

Comment: Ich denke, (1) sollte sein: Ja, will ich.

Comment: @Emanuel Ja, meistens schon, aber es gibt auch Ausnahmen (Heiratsantrag). Wie es von der Grammatik her gerechtfertigt wird weiss ich jedoch nicht :)

Comment: @Takkat: "Aber gerne" oder "aber ja" schlägt in eine ähnliche Kerbe. Da die Frage ja "Willst du" war, es also eventuell hinreichend vertraut ist, passt sicher aber auch "klar!" (oder hier in Norddeutschland auch "jo") :)

Comment: @ Layne... hey, das ist eigentlich eine superinteressante Frage :)... ich würd sie hier posten aber du hast natürlich Vortritt, wenn du willst

Comment: @Emanuel Nein danke, so sehr interessiere ich mich fuer meine Muttersprache jetzt doch nicht :)

Answer (score 10):

Wird einem *einladend* etwas zu trinken, zu essen oder zur Benutzung angeboten (auch wenn es durch ein schluffiges »willst 'n / magst 'n Kaffe?« ausgedrückt wird) ist **»ja, gerne« / »nein, danke«** die ebenso freundliche Standardantwort, »ja, bitte« geht auch.

In dieser Situation wäre »ja, will/möchte ich« eine eher untypische Verstärkung, die eine gewisse Nachdrücklichkeit oder gar Forderung vermittelt.

In einer gastronomischen *Verkaufssituation* (»Möchten's / wollen's Sahne zum Kuchen?«) wäre »ja, bitte/gerne« / »nein, danke« ebenso typisch.

Unabhängig hiervon ist es im Allgemeinen richtig, dass bei einer Bitte das Wort 'möchten' benutzt wird. Das ist jedoch ein Thema für sich…

Answer (score 5):

Du kannst mit beiden antworten, *möchten* ist bloß netter als *wollen*.

Comment: kann aber nicht muss, oder?

Comment: @VP01: Nein, du musst nicht mit "möchten" antworten. Beides ist technisch komplett korrekt, aber "möchten" ist in den meisten Fällen zu empfehlen, es sei denn, du willst nicht nett wirken ;).

Comment: @looper: Es gibt natürlich auch Fragen, auf die "Ja, ich will" durchaus nett und richtig ist... ;)

Comment: @OregonGhost: Stimmt, vorm Traualtar "Ja, ich möchte" zu sagen, wäre ziemlich seltsam. Daher meinte ich "in den meisten Fällen", auch wenn es vllt ein wenig hochgegriffen war.

Comment: @looper: Hauptsache, man [verwechselt](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0831991/quotes?qt1484057) nicht den Namen der Braut...

Answer (score 0):

Also üblicherweise gilt die Regel, dass man die Formulierung des Fragenden übernimmt - wenn der also schon "unhöflich" fragt, ob Du einen Kaffee *willst*,  dann ist die korrekte Antwort auch, "Ja, ich will einen Kaffee". Wenn Du mit "Ich möchte" antworten sollst, dann sollte der Fragende auch "Möchtest Du" fragen.

Comment: das ist genau wie ich gelernt habe.